# How extreme values of a functional can be found using R?

Tags: r

I have a functional like this :

[image: first formula]

(LaTex formula: `$v[y]=\int_0^2 (y'^2+23yy'+12y^2+3ye^{2t})dt$`)

with given start and end conditions `y(0)=-1, y(2)=18`. 
How can I find extreme values of this functional in R? I realize how it can be done for example in Excel but didn't find appropriate solution in R.

Comment: Excel can do this??  What is your `y'` ? `dy/dt` ?

Comment: in Excel I do this just like approximation: create t,y and y' and v columns and then find the solution. y' is dy/dt.

Comment: `?deriv` with `?optim` might be of use

Comment: What doe you mean by "find extreme values"?  Are you looking for a function `y` that maximizes or minimizes `v[y]`?  Are you sure excel can do this?  I'm assume your strategy is to do a discrete approximation and then optimize.  If so, this can be done in R, but I wasn't aware that excel did multidimensional nonlinear optimization.

Comment: I would be really impressed by a *valid* working Excel solution.  Could you share it with us?

Answer (score 3):

Before trying to solve such a task in a numerical setting, it might be better to lean back and think about it for a moment.

This is a problem typically treated in the mathematical discipline of "variational calculus". A necessary condition for a function `y(t)` to be an extremum of the functional (ie. the integral) is the so-called Euler-Lagrange equation, see
[Calculus of Variations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CalculusofVariations.html) at Wolfram Mathworld.

Applying it to `f(t, y, y')` as the integrand in your request, I get (please check, I can easily have made a mistake)

```
y'' - 12*y + 3/2*exp(2*t) = 0
```

You can go now and find a symbolic solution for this differential equation (with the help of a textbook, or some CAS), or solve it numerically with the help of an R package such as 'deSolve'.

PS: Solving this as an optimization problem based on discretization is possible, but may lead you on a long and stony road. I remember solving the "brachistochrone problem" to a satisfactory accuracy only by applying several hundred variables (not in R).

Comment: Interesting approach. I like it but I fear the OP was putting some collection of numeric values for `y` and `y'` into a simple solver.  Poorly worded question.

Comment: @HansWerner - I think the Euler-Lagrange equation applied to your `f(t,y,y')` gives `y'' - 12*y - 3/2*exp(2*t)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a numerical solution in R.  First the functional:

```
f<-function(y,t=head(seq(0,2,len=length(y)),-1)){
  len<-length(y)-1
  dy<-diff(y)*len/2
  y0<-(head(y,-1)+y[-1])/2
  2*sum(dy^2+23*y0*dy+12*y0^2+3*y0*exp(2*t))/len
}
```

Now the function that does the actual optimization.  The best results I got were using the BFGS optimization method, and parametrizing using `dy` rather than `y`:

```
findMinY<-function(points=100, ## number of points of evaluation
                   boundary=c(-1,18), ## boundary values
                   y0=NULL, ## optional initial value
                   method="Nelder-Mead", ## optimization method
                   dff=T) ## if TRUE, optimizes based on dy rather than y
{
  t<-head(seq(0,2,len=points),-1)
  if(is.null(y0) || length(y0)!=points)
    y0<-seq(boundary[1],boundary[2],len=points)
  if(dff)
    y0<-diff(y0)
  else
    y0<-y0[-1]
  y0<-head(y0,-1)

  ff<-function(z){
    if(dff)
      y<-c(cumsum(c(boundary[1],z)),boundary[2])
    else
      y<-c(boundary[1],z,boundary[2])
    f(y,t)
  }

  res<-optim(y0,ff,control=list(maxit=1e9),method=method)
  cat("Iterations:",res$counts,"\n")
  ymin<-res$par
  if(dff)
    c(cumsum(c(boundary[1],ymin)),boundary[2])
  else
    c(boundary[1],ymin,boundary[2])      
}
```

With 500 points of evaluation, it only takes a few seconds with BFGS:

```
> system.time(yy<-findMinY(500,method="BFGS"))
Iterations: 90 18 
   user  system elapsed 
  2.696   0.000   2.703
```

The resulting function looks like this:

```
plot(seq(0,2,len=length(yy)),yy,type='l')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

And now a solution that numerically integrates the Euler equation.

As @HansWerner pointed out, this problem boils down to applying the Euler-Lagrange equation to the integrand in OP's question, and then solving that differential equation, either analytically or numerically. In this case the relevant ODE is

```
y'' - 12*y = 3/2*exp(2*t)
subject to:
y(0) = -1
y(2) = 18
```

So this is a boundary value problem, best approached using `bvpcol(...)` in  package `bvpSolve`.

```
library(bvpSolve)
F <- function(t, y.in, pars){
  dy  <- y.in[2]
  d2y <- 12*y.in[1] + 1.5*exp(2*t)
  return(list(c(dy,d2y)))
}
init <- c(-1,NA)
end  <- c(18,NA)
t    <- seq(0, 2, by = 0.01)
sol  <- bvpcol(yini = init, yend = end, x = t, func = F)

y = function(t){    # analytic solution...
  b <- sqrt(12)
  a <- 1.5/(4-b*b)
  u <- exp(2*b)
  C1 <- ((18*u + 1) - a*(exp(4)*u-1))/(u*u - 1)
  C2 <- -1 - a - C1
  return(a*exp(2*t) + C1*exp(b*t) + C2*exp(-b*t))
}

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(t,y(t), type="l", xlim=c(0,2),ylim=c(-1,18), col="red", main="Analytical Solution")
plot(sol[,1],sol[,2], type="l", xlim=c(0,2),ylim=c(-1,18), xlab="t", ylab="y(t)", main="Numerical Solution")
```

[image]

It turns out that in this very simple example, there is an analytical solution:

```
y(t) = a * exp(2*t) + C1 * exp(sqrt(12)*t) + C2 * exp(-sqrt(12)*t)
```

where `a = -3/16` and `C1` and `C2` are determined to satisfy the boundary conditions. As the plots show, the numerical and analytic solution agree completely, and also agree with the solution provided by @mrip